# ¿Cómo puedo calibrar correctamente un sensor muscular? (EMG)

Tags: c++, c, arduino, c++11, sensor

llevo ya dos semanas con el inconveniente de que al usar el sensor muscular me lanza cada vez valores distintos, sin importar que le suba o baje la ganancia en el AO
Estuve trabajando en C++ y he visto todo tipo de vídeos al respecto, sin embargo sigo estancado.

Necesito una programación que me ayude a estabilizar la señal análoga que recibe para poder calibrarla.

```
const int sensorPin = A0;    // configuramos el pin para el sensor
const int ledPin = 9;        // configuramos el pin para el LED

// variables:
int sensorValue = 0;         // Valor del sensor 
int sensorMin = 1023;        // valor mínimo del sensor
int sensorMax = 0;           // valor máximo del sensor

void setup() {   // El LED se enciende para indicar el periodo dE calibración   
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  // Calibrar durante los primeros cinco segundos    
  while (millis() < 5000) {
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

    // Registrar el valor máximo del sensor
    if (sensorValue > sensorMax) {
      sensorMax = sensorValue;
    }

    // Registrar el valor mínimo del sensor
    if (sensorValue < sensorMin) {
      sensorMin = sensorValue;
    }
  }

  // Señal para el fin de la calibración   
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
}

void loop() {   // Leemos el sensor   
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

  // Aplicar la calibración para la lectura del sensor   
  sensorValue = map(sensorValue, sensorMin, sensorMax, 0, 255);
  // en caso de que el valor del sensor está fuera del rango   
  // visto durante la calibración   
  sensorValue = constrain(sensorValue, 0, 255);

  // se desvanecen el LED utilizando el valor de calibrado:   
  analogWrite(ledPin, sensorValue);
```

Ayuda por favor, es el proyecto con el que me graduaré y me quedan dos semanas :(

Comment: Te falta un `pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP);` en el `setup()`

Answer (score 0):

Te falta declarar el pinSensor como entrada. Si no lo declaras como entrada, las lecturas te van a dar cualquier cosa.

No tengo un sensor EMG, así que use un divisor de tensión con un foto-resistor y una resistencia fija. El pin A0 queda conectado entre las dos, midiendo las diferencias de voltaje cuando el foto-resistor cambia ante variaciones de luz.

[image: Arduino con foto sensor]

Modifique tu sketch para mostrar los valores leidos. Siempre hay que ir mostrando las lecturas para descubrir que está pasando.

Fijate que en este sketch **no** programamos A0 como pin de entrada

```
const int sensorPin = A0;    
// configuramos el pin para el sensor 
const int ledPin = 9;        
// configuramos el pin para el LED
// variables: 
int sensorValue = 0;         
// Valor del sensor 
int sensorMin = 1023;        
// valor mínimo del sensor  
int sensorMax = 0;           
// valor máximo del sensor

void setup() {   
  // El LED se enciende para indicar el periodo de calibración   
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);   
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  // pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Calibrar durante los primeros cinco segundos
  Serial.println("Start");
  while (millis() < 10000) {
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    // Registrar el valor máximo del sensor
    if (sensorValue > sensorMax) {
      sensorMax = sensorValue;
    }

    // Registrar el valor mínimo del sensor
    if (sensorValue < sensorMin) {
      sensorMin = sensorValue;
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.print("Min/Max = ");
  Serial.print(sensorMin);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(sensorMax);
  Serial.println("End");
  // Señal para el fin de la calibración   
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
  }

  void loop() {   // Leemos el sensor   
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.print("Sensor raw = ");
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
    // Aplicar la calibración para la lectura del sensor   
    sensorValue = map(sensorValue, sensorMin, sensorMax, 0, 255);

    // en caso de que el valor del sensor está fuera del rango   
    // visto durante la calibración   
    sensorValue = constrain(sensorValue, 0, 255);

    // se desvanecen el LED utilizando el valor de calibrado:    
    //analogWrite(ledPin, sensorValue);
    Serial.print(" Sensor ajustado = ");
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
    delay(250);
  }
```

Con esto, la calibración da:

```
Start
5
6
5
43
43
41
42
42
42
17
Min/Max = 5, 43
End
```

Ahora, si programamos A0 como entrada, manteniendo el mismo circuito:

```
void setup() {   
  // El LED se enciende para indicar el periodo de calibración   
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);   
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

la situación cambia:

```
Start
123
318
315
119
121
118
116
115
114
118
Min/Max = 114, 318
End
```